# When is my document saved using Mongoose save function?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

My question is in the function below in the commented code.

```
newUser = new User();
newUser.save(function(err){
            if(err) console.log('error saving user');
            // is my user saved at this point? Can I modify
            // the user in here or is this pre-save?
            });
```

Comment: It's saved right away, but the `save` method is async because the middleware calls native code to do the save

Comment: @chridam oops, in my real code I did it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as the code is executed it is saved. There is some validation that occurs in the middleware, but it is instant otherwise.